# Expanding and creating code templates in Eclipse when using emacs keybindings

Tags: eclipse, templates, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I expand code templates in Eclipse when using the emacs keybindings?
Is there a hotkey for turning selected code into a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently for C/C++ you have to enable templates in `Window -> Preferences-> C/C++ -> Editor -> Content-assist -> Advanced`.

Uncheck everything except templates and check templates in both the upper and lower boxes.

Then in the editor type a template name like:

```
for
```

and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to expand it into:

```
for (var = 0; var < max; ++var) {

}
```

Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to fill in the blanks.

NOTE: eclipse 3.5

Comment: Thanks a lot,
How can I change the default expanding shortcuts provided by eclipse?